# I added a new calendar using my laptop, but my Android phone can't find it after syncing

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, calendar

I used my laptop to remove two calendars and add one calendar to my Google Calendar account. After syncing, the Calendar app on my Android (2.2) phone knows that I deleted the two calendars, but does not know about the calendar that I added. Is this a common problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the calendar app's menu, see if the newly added calendar shows up in My Calendars.

Select and sync your account.

If it doesn't or you have problems, clear the data cache from within Android's main settings > Applications section and resync.

Comment: 1. The newly added calendar did not show up in My Calendars. 2. Re-syncing my account (by de-selecting "sync calendar" and re-selecting it) did not fix the problem. 3. Clearing my data (by going to main settings > applications > calendar data > clear data) and re-syncing (by the same steps as #2) did fix it!

Comment: Worked for me too. Note though that clearing the calendar data (appears to be called Calendar Storage in Android 2.3) will delete *all* entries in the local, non-google calendar too.